# Yubikey alternative with fingerprint reader

Tags: security, fingerprint-scanner

does anyone know a yubikey-like hardware token, but with a fingerprint reader instead of just a capacitive button like the one on a yubikey?

Answer (score 1):

Yubico announced the [YubiKey Bio](https://www.yubico.com/2019/11/yubico-reveals-first-biometric-yubikey-at-microsoft-ignite/), which seems to do exactly that.